# .htaccess redirect not redirecting

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite, mod-alias

I am trying to Redirect pages to new location on the same website using .htaccess
the physical file name is displayitems.php but there is a rule in .htaccess

```
RewriteRule ^buy-online-(.*) ./displayitems.php?url=$1
```

which is to handle the user friends URLs and works well.

Now i want to redirects these user friendly urls to new location which is on the same website for eg.

`redirect https://example.com/buy-online-alhabib-rings4-sku-1658906163  https://example.com/products/jewelry/buy-online-alhabib-rings4-sku-1658906163 [R=301]`

`redirect https://example.com/buy-online-alhabib-rings3-sku-1658906162  https://example.com/products/jewelry/buy-online-alhabib-rings3-sku-1658906162 [R=301]`

`redirect https://example.com/buy-online-alhabib-rings2-sku-1658906161  https://example.com/products/jewelry/buy-online-alhabib-rings2-sku-1658906161 [R=301]`

`redirect https://example.com/buy-online-alhabib-rings1-sku-1658906160  https://example.com/products/jewelry/buy-online-alhabib-rings1-sku-1658906160 [R=301]`

**these user friendly url doesn't have any extensions like ".php" ".htm" etc**

but nothing happening.

Comment: yes these all urls start with https://website.com/buy-online-(.*) But redirected to https://website.come/products/Relavent category/ which is dynamic for each url

Comment: The `Redirect` directive matches against the URL _path_, not the full absolute URL. The examples and description should make that very clear, https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_alias.html#redirect

Comment: @anubhava i will write redirect for each url

Comment: _Side note:_ I would recommend you read about the [front controller pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Front_controller) and use a [router](https://packagist.org/?query=router) to handle the URL's, which you then set up in your PHP code in a more intuitive way, instead of adding a bunch of different rules in your htaccess. It will also make your app more portable between different web servers (not all read htaccess files). It's a very common pattern these days.

Comment: @M.Eriksson what if i use php header to do the redirect? I was avoiding that because maybe it will effect on efficiency

Comment: @CBroe i will check this as well

Comment: I doubt having some extra conditional redirects in the beginning of your code would noticeably affect performance of your application. If it would, you probably have much bigger issues with your code and/or server specs.

Comment: I have added this code in php file to check if url doesn't contain \products\ than redirect it to new location with the same name, for testing i just redirect it with 302 once all tested i will change it to 301 


``if (strpos($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], "/products/") === false) {            
 $NewAddress = strtolower("Location:". $ini['website_address_https'] . "products/".$Product['categoriesname']."/".$Product['BrandName'].$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
 header("$NewAddress",TRUE,302);   
}``

Answer (score 0):

I have added this code in php file to check if url doesn't contain \products\ than redirect it to new location with the same name, for testing i just redirect it with 302 once all tested i will change it to 301

`if (strpos($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], "/products/") === false) {                                                 $NewAddress = strtolower("Location:". $ini['website_address_https'] . "products/".$Product['categoriesname']."/".$Product['BrandName'].$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']); header("$NewAddress",TRUE,302);          }`

Answer (score 0):

> `redirect https://example.com/buy-online-alhabib-rings4-sku-1658906163  https://example.com/products/jewelry/buy-online-alhabib-rings4-sku-1658906163 [R=301]`

There are 3 main issues here:

1. The mod_alias `Redirect` directive takes a root-relative URL-path (starting with a slash) as the source URL, not an absolute URL. So the above will never match.
2. You have mixed syntax with mod_rewrite. `[R=301]` is a `RewriteRule` (mod_rewrite) *flags* argument and has nothing to do with the mod_alias `Redirect` directive. `Redirect` takes the HTTP status code as an optional second argument. eg. `Redirect 301 /buy-online-alhabib-rings4-sku-1658906163 ...`
3. Since you are using mod_rewrite (ie. `RewriteRule`) for your internal rewrite, you should use mod_rewrite for external redirects as well to avoid potential conflicts. These redirects then need to go before your internal rewrite.

Additionally,

4. In the 4 redirects you have posted it looks like you are simply injecting `/products/jewelry` at the start of the URL-path. This does not need 4 separate rules, providing you are wanting to redirect all URLs that following this particular format.

Try the following instead:

```
RewriteEngine On

# Inject (redirect) "/product/jewelry" at the start of the URL-path
RewriteRule ^buy-online-alhabib-rings\d-sku-\d+$ /products/jewelry/$0 [R=301,L]

# Internal rewrite
RewriteRule ^buy-online-(.*) displayitems.php?url=$1 [L]
```

The `$0` backreference in the first rule contains the entire URL-path that is matched by the `RewriteRule` *pattern*.

Note that I also removed `./` from the start of the *substitution* string in the last rule. This is unnecessary here.